# MongoDB: filter (findOne/updateOne..) by ObjectId not working or "ObjectId is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

None of the following filters worked when I tried to update a document, in JS/Node.js filtered by "_id", where the value is the generic ObjectId (`ObjectId('6365050650c6be6d5d090135')`) :

```
{_id : ObjectId(123....7890)}
{_id : ObjectId('123....7890')}
{_id : "ObjectId('123....7890')"}
+ other variantions I came across
```

Nothing worked for me. I got `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined` or no errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be able to spawn new ObjectIds, so enable that first:

```
import { MongoClient, ObjectId } from "mongodb";
```

and filter like this:

```
{_id : new ObjectId('123....7890')}
```

[image]

Actually this is what MongoDB Compass "exports to language" (see screenshot above) when you filter

```
{_id: ObjectId('123....7890')}
```

I am pretty sure this is obvious to many, but it took me quite a while to resolve it, so I hope this saves you some time.

Answer (score -1):

Either use **ObjectId** from **mongodb** client like so:

```
import { ObjectId } from "mongodb";

{ _id: new ObjectId('6365050650c6be6d5d090135')}
```

or if you are using **mongoose** then:

```
{ _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId('6365050650c6be6d5d090135') }
```

or with mongoose you can directly pass in the objectid string and the mongoose model will handle it for you like so:

```
{ _id: '6365050650c6be6d5d090135' }
```

I am not sure if the above possible can be done with mongodb client too.